# Self study vs pre requisite credit hours for graduate admissions

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am going through the websites of various mathematics graduate schools. Most graduate schools typically require approximately 30-33 credit hours worth of courses.

I have done only approximately 25 credit hour worth of courses, as I am a non mathematics major who has course work in both physics (primarily) and mathematics, and I most probably wish to enroll in a mathematics school and specialize in mathematical physics.

My question is:

> Is it possible for someone to be (seriously) considered at a school if one hasn't completed the required number of credit hours/pre-requisites? I'm asking this question assuming the applicant scores decently on the GRE and has self study under one's belt to compensate for the courses not taken. Hopefully, the self study could be corroborated in a letter.

Comment: This could work, but your chances of success as a Third World applicant would be increased if the learning were documented in a transcript.  Jumping over to math for grad school is one of the more difficult jumps to make.  I'm glad to hear you've started reading math departments' application instructions. // An additional advantage to taking courses in addition to doing self-study is that coursework can garner you additional math-focused letters of reference.

Comment: @aparente001 Perfect. Did you see the message I posted in chat board(s)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to find your other room.  Can you post a link?